# How to override route where to redirect user if not authenticated?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

I already have this `app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     */
    protected function redirectTo(Request $request): ?string
    {
        return $request->expectsJson() ? null : route('home');
    }
}
```

The problem is that sometime Laravel in case user is not authenticated is traveling trought this:

`vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler .php: 570`

```
 protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)

    {

        return $this->shouldReturnJson($request, $exception)

                    ? response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401)

                    : redirect()->guest($exception->redirectTo() ?? route('login'));

    }
```

Where can I override this!?! I have no 'login' named route ! I need to return to route named 'home'.

Comment: Are you sure that this `$request->expectsJson()` does not return null? your code seems to be right as long as you are overriding the redirectTo method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must change the code in your handler, which is available at the path `App\Exceptions\Handler.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Throwable;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * Convert an authentication exception into a response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException  $exception
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        return $this->shouldReturnJson($request, $exception)
            ? response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401)
            : redirect()->guest(route('home'));
    }
}
```